# coloring chairs in circle combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ chairs in a circle. One of them is a high chair and the rest $n-1$ chairs are short ones. I need to prove that the number of possibilities to color $k$ of them so no two colored chairs will be next to each other is $$\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$$

I tried picking up the k colored chairs which is $\binom{n}{k}$ and then put another k uncolored chairs (one next to each colored) which is $\binom{n-k}{k}$ and the rest just put in a circle which is $(n-2k)!$.
to conclude $$\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{k}(n-2k)!$$
however that doesn't work right.

Comment: Why is it important that one is a high chair?

Comment: @JoaoNoch  We can use the high chair as a reference point.  The remaining chairs can be treated as a linear arrangement relative to the high chair.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a variation on stars and bars, where the colored chairs are bars, and the uncolored ones are stars. The circle complicates things slightly, but we just break into two cases:

Case 1: The high chair is colored. In this case, the remainder of the circle consists of $n-k$ uncolored chairs and $k-1$ colored; using stars and bars (note that there are $k-1$ bars, not bins), there are ${n-k-1} \choose {k-1}$ possible arrangements.

Case 2: The high chair is uncolored. Now the remainder of the circle has $n-k-1$ uncolored chairs and $k$ colored chairs. In a slight variation on stars and bars, a colored chair can be inserted between two uncolored chairs or on either end (that is, the chairs next to the high chair), so there are ${n-k} \choose k$ possible arrangements.

The total is the sum of these two figures. Given the answer posed in the question, perhaps there is a hidden assumption that the high chair is not colored.

Comment: In Case 1, the two chairs adjacent to the high chair must not be colored.

Comment: Yes. I think the stars and bars argument accounts for that. In the second case I had to loosen this constraint, allowing the end "bins" to be empty, because the chairs next to the high chair could be colored.

Comment: I ended up confirming your answer with a different approach.